# Deposit Access Database

Tags: c#, database

I am working on Bank project for which I have written this code
for Deposit/Withdrawal Transaction however, I am getting errors as"

```
Error   5   'ChattBank.DepWithDraw' does not contain a definition for 'balance' and no extension method 'balance' accepting a first argument of type 'ChattBank.DepWithDraw' 
Error   3   Use of unassigned local variable 'depAmount'
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Withdraw and Deposit Access Database mdb](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29786039/withdraw-and-deposit-access-database-mdb)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You haven't defined the variable `balance` as a field. You are also trying to use `depAmount` before you stored anything to it.